# C++/SFML Boid/Flocking Simulation

Tags: c++, simulation, sfml

I have created a flocking simulation based on Craig Reynolds Boids. Could you give me some feedback on my code? I am a newbie and would really appreciate some criticism.

Files:

- Boid - this is the representation of a bird like object.
- Flock - this controls and manages the flock of boids.

Flock.h:

```
#include "Boid.h"
#include <vector>
#include <random>
#include <chrono>
#ifndef FLOCK_H
#define FLOCK_H

class Flock
{
private:
    std::vector<Boid> m_boidStorage;
    sf::RenderWindow* m_winPtr = nullptr;
    sf::Texture* m_t;

    std::uniform_real_distribution<float> m_uniform;
    int m_seed;
    std::mt19937 m_randomEngine;
    std::normal_distribution<float> m_gaussian;

    float maxForce;
    float maxVelocity;
    float minimumSeperation;


    void Alignment(float multiplier);
    void Cohesion(float multiplier);
    void Seperation(float multiplier);
    void Move();
    void MassCalculate();

    float AbsBoidDistance(const Boid& boid1, const Boid& boid2);
    sf::Vector2f VecBoidDistance(const Boid& boid1, const Boid& boid2);
    float VectorMagnitude(const sf::Vector2f& vec);
    void LimitMagnitude(sf::Vector2f& vec, const float& magnitude);
    void SetMagnitude(sf::Vector2f& vec, const float& magnitude);
    bool CompareMemLocs(const Boid& boid1, const Boid& boid2);

    void Borders(Boid& boid);


public:
    enum FORCECONSTANTS
    {
        KA = 0, KC, KS
    };
    float kA;
    float kS;
    float kC;

    Flock(sf::RenderWindow* winPtr);
    void Display();
    void Update();
    void ChangeConstants(FORCECONSTANTS x, bool direction);
    void AddBoid(bool external);

};

#endif
```

Flock.cpp:
Originally, I had calculated the Cohesion, Seperation and Alignment Forces by individual functions, however merging the algorithms together in to a single function, called `void Flock::MassCalculate()` has allowed me to increase performance by reducing the number of checks.

```
#include "Flock.h"
#include "Constants.h"
#include <iostream>

Flock::Flock(sf::RenderWindow* winPtr)
    :m_winPtr(winPtr)
{
    minimumSeperation = 40;
    maxForce = 0.01;
    maxVelocity = 0.75;
    kA = 1.4;
    kC = 1.5;
    kS = 1.7;

    m_seed = std::chrono::steady_clock::now().time_since_epoch().count();
    m_randomEngine.seed(m_seed);
    std::normal_distribution<float> igaussian(WIDTH / 2, 0.2);
    std::uniform_real_distribution<float> uniformDist(-1, 1);


    m_uniform = uniformDist;
    m_gaussian = igaussian;


    for (int i = 0; i < TOTAL_BOIDS; i++)
    {
        AddBoid(false);
    }
}
void Flock::AddBoid(bool external)
{
    if (external)
    {
        Boid b1{ sf::Vector2f{float(WIDTH / 2),float(HEIGHT / 2)}, sf::Vector2f{0,0} };
        m_boidStorage.push_back(b1);
        maxVelocity += 0.05;
    }
    else
    {
        Boid b2(sf::Vector2f{ m_gaussian(m_randomEngine), m_gaussian(m_randomEngine) }, sf::Vector2f{ float(m_uniform(m_randomEngine)), float(m_uniform(m_randomEngine)) });
        m_boidStorage.push_back(b2);
    }

}
sf::Vector2f Flock::VecBoidDistance(const Boid& boid1, const Boid& boid2)
{
    sf::Vector2f b1 = boid1.boid.getPosition();
    sf::Vector2f b2 = boid2.boid.getPosition();
    return b2 - b1;
}
float Flock::AbsBoidDistance(const Boid& boid1, const Boid& boid2)
{
    sf::Vector2f b1 = boid1.boid.getPosition();
    sf::Vector2f b2 = boid2.boid.getPosition();
    return sqrt(pow((b2.x - b1.x), 2) + pow((b2.y - b1.y), 2));
}
float Flock::VectorMagnitude(const sf::Vector2f& vec)
{
    return sqrt(pow(vec.x, 2) + pow(vec.y, 2));
}
void Flock::SetMagnitude(sf::Vector2f& vec, const float& newmagnitude)
{
    float currentMag = VectorMagnitude(vec);
    vec /= currentMag;
    vec *= newmagnitude;
}
void Flock::LimitMagnitude(sf::Vector2f& vec,const float& limit)
{
    float magnitude = VectorMagnitude(vec);
    if (magnitude > limit)
    {
        SetMagnitude(vec, limit);
    }
}
bool Flock::CompareMemLocs(const Boid& boid1, const Boid& boid2)
{
    return &boid1 != &boid2;
}

void Flock::Borders(Boid& boid)
{
    if (boid.boid.getPosition().x < -boid.m_radius)
    {
        boid.boid.setPosition(sf::Vector2f{ WIDTH + boid.m_radius, boid.boid.getPosition().y });
    }
    if (boid.boid.getPosition().x > WIDTH + boid.m_radius)
    {
        boid.boid.setPosition(sf::Vector2f{ 0 - boid.m_radius, boid.boid.getPosition().y });
    }
    if (boid.boid.getPosition().y < -boid.m_radius)
    {
        boid.boid.setPosition(sf::Vector2f{ boid.boid.getPosition().x, HEIGHT + boid.m_radius });
    }
    if (boid.boid.getPosition().y > HEIGHT + boid.m_radius)
    {
        boid.boid.setPosition(sf::Vector2f{ boid.boid.getPosition().x, 0 - boid.m_radius });
    }
}
void Flock::Display()
{
    Boid B(sf::Vector2f{ WIDTH / 2,HEIGHT / 2 }, sf::Vector2f{ 0,0 });
    m_winPtr->clear();
    for (const Boid& boid : m_boidStorage)
    {

        m_winPtr->draw(boid.boid);
    }
    m_winPtr->display();
}
void Flock::Move()
{
    for (Boid& boid : m_boidStorage)
    {
        boid.Move();
        Borders(boid);
    }
}

void Flock::Update()
{
    MassCalculate();

    Move();
    Display();

}


void Flock::MassCalculate()
{
    float alignmentperceptionradius = 50;
    float cohesionperceptionradius = 50;
    float seperationperceptionradius = 50;
    for (Boid& thisBoid : m_boidStorage)
    {
        unsigned int alignmentCount = 0;
        unsigned int cohesionCount = 0;
        unsigned int seperationCount = 0;

        sf::Vector2f AlignmentForce = {};
        sf::Vector2f CohesionForce = {};
        sf::Vector2f SeperationForce = {};
        sf::Vector2f Distance = {};

        for (const Boid& otherBoid : m_boidStorage)
        {
            float d = AbsBoidDistance(thisBoid, otherBoid);
            if (CompareMemLocs(thisBoid, otherBoid) && d < alignmentperceptionradius)
            {
                AlignmentForce += otherBoid.m_Velocity;
                alignmentCount++;
            }
            if (CompareMemLocs(thisBoid, otherBoid) && d < cohesionperceptionradius)
            {
                CohesionForce += otherBoid.boid.getPosition();
                cohesionCount++;
            }
            if (CompareMemLocs(thisBoid, otherBoid) && d < seperationperceptionradius)
            {
                Distance = thisBoid.boid.getPosition() - otherBoid.boid.getPosition();
                Distance /= (d*d);
                SeperationForce += Distance;
                seperationCount++;
            }


        }
        if (alignmentCount > 0)
        {
            AlignmentForce /= float(alignmentCount);
            SetMagnitude(AlignmentForce, maxVelocity);
            AlignmentForce = AlignmentForce - thisBoid.m_Velocity;
            LimitMagnitude(AlignmentForce, maxForce);
        }
        if (cohesionCount > 0)
        {
            CohesionForce /= float(cohesionCount);
            CohesionForce = CohesionForce - thisBoid.boid.getPosition();

            SetMagnitude(CohesionForce, maxVelocity);
            CohesionForce = CohesionForce - thisBoid.m_Velocity;
            LimitMagnitude(CohesionForce, maxForce);
        }
        if (seperationCount > 0)
        {
            SeperationForce /= float(seperationCount);
            SetMagnitude(SeperationForce, maxVelocity);
            SeperationForce = SeperationForce - thisBoid.m_Velocity;
            LimitMagnitude(SeperationForce, maxForce);
        }


        AlignmentForce *= kA;
        thisBoid.AddForce(AlignmentForce);
        CohesionForce *= kC;
        thisBoid.AddForce(CohesionForce);
        SeperationForce *= kS;
        thisBoid.AddForce(SeperationForce);
    }

}
void Flock::ChangeConstants(FORCECONSTANTS x, bool direction)
{
    if (x == FORCECONSTANTS::KA)
    {
        (direction) ? kA += 0.1 : kA -= 0.1;
        std::cout << "kA: " << kA << std::endl;
    }
    if (x == FORCECONSTANTS::KC)
    {
        (direction) ? kC += 0.1 : kC -= 0.1;
        std::cout << "kC: " << kC << std::endl;
    }
    if (x == FORCECONSTANTS::KS)
    {
        (direction) ? kS += 0.1 : kS -= 0.1;
        std::cout << "kS: " << kS << std::endl;
    }

}
```

Boid.h

```
#include <SFML/Graphics.hpp>
#ifndef  BOID_H
#define BOID_H
struct Boid
{
    sf::CircleShape boid;
    float m_radius;

    sf::Vector2f m_Velocity;
    sf::Vector2f m_Force;
    Boid(const sf::Vector2f& init_Pos, const sf::Vector2f init_Vel);
    void AddForce(const sf::Vector2f& force);
    void Move();
};
#endif // ! BOID_H
```

Boid.cpp:

```
#include "Boid.h"
Boid::Boid(const sf::Vector2f& init_pos, const sf::Vector2f init_vel)
    :m_Velocity(init_vel)
{
    m_radius = 5;
    boid.setPosition(init_pos);
    boid.setFillColor(sf::Color::White);
    boid.setOutlineThickness(0);
    boid.setOutlineColor(sf::Color::White);
    boid.setPointCount(50);
    boid.setRadius(m_radius);
    boid.setOrigin(m_radius, m_radius);
}
void Boid::AddForce(const sf::Vector2f& force)
{
    m_Force += force;
    m_Velocity += force;
}
void Boid::Move()
{

    boid.move(m_Velocity);
}
```

Main.cpp:

```
#include "Flock.h"
#include <string>
#include "Constants.h"
#include <iostream>

#include <iomanip>
int main()
{
    std::string myTitle = "Boids";
    sf::RenderWindow myWindow(sf::VideoMode(WIDTH, HEIGHT), myTitle, sf::Style::Default);

    Flock f(&myWindow);
    while (myWindow.isOpen())
    {
        sf::Event evnt;
        while (myWindow.pollEvent(evnt))
        {
                switch (evnt.type)
                {
                    case sf::Event::EventType::Closed:
                    {
                        myWindow.close();
                    }
                    case sf::Event::EventType::KeyPressed:
                    {
                        if (sf::Keyboard::isKeyPressed(sf::Keyboard::Key::Space))
                        {
                            f.AddBoid(true);
                        }
                        if (sf::Keyboard::isKeyPressed(sf::Keyboard::Key::Num1))
                        {

                            f.ChangeConstants(f.KA, true);
                        }
                        if (sf::Keyboard::isKeyPressed(sf::Keyboard::Key::Num2))
                        {
                            f.ChangeConstants(f.KA, false);
                        }
                        if (sf::Keyboard::isKeyPressed(sf::Keyboard::Key::Num3))
                        {
                            f.ChangeConstants(f.KC, true);
                        }
                        if (sf::Keyboard::isKeyPressed(sf::Keyboard::Key::Num4))
                        {
                            f.ChangeConstants(f.KC, false);
                        }
                        if (sf::Keyboard::isKeyPressed(sf::Keyboard::Key::Num5))
                        {
                            f.ChangeConstants(f.KS, true);

                        }
                        if (sf::Keyboard::isKeyPressed(sf::Keyboard::Key::Num6))
                        {
                            f.ChangeConstants(f.KS, false);
                        }
                    }
                }
        }

        f.Update();
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi, in the future please make sure that your title is a description of the purpose of your code, as I edited for you. Can you also indicate in your question: does your code work (a screenshot may be helpful for graphics)? A description of Craig Reynolds Boids may help reviewers understand the mechanism of your code as well.

Answer (score 3):

In all, this is a nice, solid effort, especially for a self-avowed "newbie."  Keep up the good work!  With that, here are some things that may help you improve your program.

### Use SFML more fully

I would suggest that it would be a good idea to have the `Flock` class derive from both the `sf::Transformable` and `sf::Drawable` classes.  Your `Flock::Display()` would then become an implementation of `Flock::draw`. See the [SFML tutorial on creating entities](https://www.sfml-dev.org/tutorials/2.5/graphics-vertex-array.php#creating-an-sfml-like-entity) for more details.

### Think carefully about inheiritance

The `Boid` class is currently this:

```
struct Boid
{
    sf::CircleShape boid;
    float m_radius;

sf::Vector2f m_Velocity;
sf::Vector2f m_Force;
Boid(const sf::Vector2f& init_Pos, const sf::Vector2f init_Vel);
void AddForce(const sf::Vector2f& force);
void Move();
};
```

I would make several changes to this:

```
struct Boid : public sf::CircleShape
{
    float m_radius = 2;
    sf::Vector2f m_Velocity;
    sf::Vector2f m_Force;
    Boid(const sf::Vector2f& init_Pos, const sf::Vector2f init_Vel);
    void AddForce(const sf::Vector2f& force);
};
```

I've changed the `Boid` to inherit from `sf::CircleShape` which cleans things up.  For example, lines like these:

```
sf::Vector2f b1 = boid1.boid.getPosition();
sf::Vector2f b2 = boid2.boid.getPosition();
```

are now a bit simpler with this:

```
sf::Vector2f b1 = boid1.getPosition();
sf::Vector2f b2 = boid2.getPosition();
```

I also moved the default value for `m_radius` into the declaration rather than the constructor.  Finally, I removed the `Move` function entirely, since we can now use `sf::CircleShape::move` directly:

```
void Flock::Move()
{
    for (Boid& boid : m_boidStorage)
    {
        boid.move(boid.m_Velocity);
        Borders(boid);
    }
}
```

However, see the next suggestion.

### Think carefully about class responsibilities

It seems to me that `Borders` should be a function of `Boid` rather than of `Flock`.  Just pass in `width` and `height` and I think you'll find it a much nicer looking piece of code.  Also, `Borders` is a noun rather than a verb which makes it a somewhat misleading name for a function.  I'd call it `Wrap` instead.  Similarly, the only uses of `m_randomEngine`, `m_uniform`, `m_gaussian` are within `AddBoid` which strongly suggests to me that they would be better as static members of `Boid` and used for a default constructor of `Boid`.

### Put default values in the class definition

Rather than assigning values in the constructor, such as for `kA`, `kB`, etc. it's better to put those into the class definition.  If you do that and provide a default `Boid` constructor as mentioned above, your `Flock` constructor could look like this:

```
Flock::Flock(sf::RenderWindow* winPtr) :
    m_boidStorage(TOTAL_BOIDS),
    m_winPtr(winPtr)
{
}
```

This also simplifies `AddBoid` by removing the need for a passed parameter.

### Use `emplace_back` instead of `push_back` where appropriate

We don't really need to separately construct a `Boid` and push it onto the `std::vector`.  Instead, we can do both in a single step:

```
void Flock::AddBoid()
{
    static const sf::Vector2f middle{ WIDTH / 2.0, HEIGHT / 2.0 };
    static const sf::Vector2f zero{ 0, 0 };
    m_boidStorage.emplace_back(middle, zero);
    maxVelocity += 0.05;
}
```

This assumes that the previous suggestion is also used.

### Watch out for missing `break`s

A common error in C++ is to forget to put a `break;` at the bottom of each `case` to prevent it from falling through.  There is such a missing `break;` in `Main.cpp`.

### Use `const` where appropriate

Helper functions such as `VectorMagnitude` don't modify the underlying `Flock` object and so should be `const`.  However, in this case, see the next suggestion instead.

### Omit helper functions from the interface

There's no need to use `VectorMagnitude` outside of the `Flock` implementation code, so I'd recommend that it (and the similar functions) be non-class member `static` functions instead.

### Eliminate unused functions

The `VecBoidDistance` is never used and can be eliminated.

### Consider refactoring using objects

The `MassCalculate` function has a lot of nearly duplicate code.  I would be inclined to refactor that into three `Influence` objects with `Influence` being a pure virtual base class that would do all of the common stuff and two virual functions `updateForce` and `applyForce`.

Comment: I really appreciate the feedback. I will implement these right away! Edward, I am in desperate need of a mentor since none of my friends know how to code. Would you be so kind so as to help me improve my code in the future? I would really, really appreciate it. I understand if you do not want to do this however.

Comment: That's what we're here for.  You might also participate in [the 2nd monitor](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/8595/the-2nd-monitor) if you have questions.

Comment: Edward in your point "Omit helper functions from the interface", where would you put these functions instead? In main.cpp, or a separate header called "helper.h"/ any other spot?

Comment: Leave them exactly where they are and make them `static`.  You don't need a header file for those.